# C# Optimization of nested For loops

Tags: c#

I am trying to improve my code's execution speed. Through the C#.NET Diagnostic tools I found that the below piece of code is slowing down my program significantly as I loop through it 10,000 times. I would like input on optimization for this part of code.

```
long length = Random_Vector_Size;

Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, length), (range) =>
{
      for (q = 1; q <= Random_Vector_Size; q++)
      {
          U[q - 1] = MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.Normal.InvCDF(0.00, 1.00, instance.genrand_real3());
      }
});


for (p = 1; p <= Random_Vector_Size; p++)
{
    C[p - 1] = 0;
    Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, length), (range) =>
    {
        for (q = 1; q <= Random_Vector_Size; q++)
        {
            C[p - 1] += M[p - 1][q - 1] * U[q - 1];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please note Random_Vector_Size is 140.

Comment: With Parallel.ForEach I run in to array index out of bound exception.

Comment: how to ask at code review?

Comment: What's `C`, `M`, `U`? The problem is likely that collection indexing

Comment: this is a question for code review stack, if you have a problem where something needs to be fixed this is the place, otherwise https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if your place

Comment: C & U are double array of 140 size. M is jagged array of double[140][140]

Comment: Start with: why do you believe that parallelizing is a good idea?  Do you have evidence that this is (1) CPU bound, (2) parallelizable?

Comment: "With Parallel.ForEach I run in to array index out of bound exception" -- then your code is **wrong**.  Do not try to make it faster!  Make it correct!

Comment: Are you aware that your lambdas are closing over variables?  Variables vary.  **They will vary inside the lambdas**.

Comment: I know that might be beyond the scope of the question, but what are you actually trying to do? Maybe there are some good algorithmns out there already for your problem :)

Comment: without parallel it works absolutely fine.

Comment: I know there is no "inline" keyword in c#, but it may be good to put this directly into the calling code, that is, if it is currently in a function.

Comment: there are no readily available algorithms, I am trying to simulate particular math parameters.

Comment: My suggestion would be to remove all the parallelism and use a basic `for` loop. Get your code working and make sure it is working correctly. Do your performance test and see if it is upto performance goals.

Comment: @CodingYoshi yes did that and without parallelism it works perfect. I am now trying to make it faster.

Comment: Seriously, *stop closing over loop variables*. Everything will crash. This is a very common mistake.

Comment: @EricLippert Not the question asker, but curious and a little out of the loop -- I thought closing functionality on for loops changed in C# 5 to work like Java (silently creating a duplicate)?

Comment: @SomeGuy: We changed `foreach` loops but not `for` loops. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 0):

You have two different cases with your loops.

In the first case, it looks like you're populating an array with values from the call to `InvCDF`.  A parallel approach makes sense here if the function is processor-intensive, but it's easy for the `Parallel` setup overhead to swamp the benefits of computing your results in parallel.

In the second case, it looks like you're doing a pretty simple calculation:

4 array lookups
1 multiplication
1 addition (dependent on previous steps).

Parallelism isn't likely to give any benefits in such a scenario, especially given the nature of the sum-of-products calculations you're doing.

You might get some benefits from parallelizing your outer `for` loop rather than the inner one.  Run a benchmark to check.